# Using a svg file in JS for a strategy game

Tags: javascript, xml, svg, discord, discord.js

Basically, I am trying to make a bot into an application called Discord, and I have a problem:

This is a bot related to war strategy games, like Hearts of Iron and Civilization.

You have a “roll” command using which you can attack a place, and depending on if you win, the place will be under your control.

Now the problem here is, that these “places” happen to be states and provinces; all of them.

I have a SVG picture with all of this data, it is 4.8mb, and has, if I remember right, around 17-18k lines of code (as XML).

Is there any way, that I could be able to use the XML picture and its paths etc with JS?
Should I do it with e.g. Canvas or something else?

The map would be shown using the “map” command

If you don’t know what Discord is: https://discord.gg

The svg picture: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d9/Blank_Map_World_Secondary_Political_Divisions.svg 1

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can assign each path an id with id=“” and then use getElementById. You can also give each path an onclick() function and assign the paths to a class to provide functionality like colour change on hover.